# How to display dropdown menu link in only mobile browser not desktop browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, mobile-browser

```
  <li class="megamenu-content">
    <div class="megamenu-content-wrapper clearfix">
      <ul class="col-lg-3  col-sm-3 col-md-3 ">
          <li class="cat-header">SHOW MEMBERS</li>
          <li><a class='dropdown-menu-link' href='/new-members/'>New Members</a></li>
          <li><a class='dropdown-menu-link' href='/old-members/'>Old Members</a></li>
          <li><a class='mobile-only' href='/main-page/'>Back to Page</a></li>         
       </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">
          var isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ? true : false;
           if(isMobile) {
            document.getElementById('mobile-only').innerHtml = "Back to page"
           }
        </script>
```

I am trying to show a content in dropdown menu in only mobile browser but it doesn't work. If you have any different idea, you are also welcome :)
Thanks.

Comment: There's no element with `mobile-only` ID

Comment: `mobile-only` is a class, not an id.  Try `getElementsByClassName("mobile-only")[0]` or add a `mobile-only` id to that `<a />` element.

Comment: How about my 27" tablet? Should I see that link in a such big tablet? What is the real reason to show this link in mobile browsers only?

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, i changed to getElementsByClassName("mobile-only")[0] and it doesnt work either. I think my approach doesnt work properly. Some of sources show using @media css...

Comment: As media queries are leaning on the size of the screen, that's more likely what you need. The used OS is rarely meaningful when creating the layout of a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your mobile-only class to `display:none`

then use media query to specify your device's browser width

```
@media screen and (max-width: mobile-width-here) {
    .mobile-only { display: block; }
}
```